Error updating Flutter: "Process exited abnormally with exit code 128"
I'm trying to update Flutter to version 3.24.1 using the flutter upgrade command, but I keep encountering the following error
It seems to be a network-related issue with Git. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Retried the flutter upgrade command multiple times.
Increased Git's buffer size with git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000.
Checked my internet connection
Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I resolve this problem and successfully upgrade Flutter?
